# Embedded and references in a data model - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to create a mongodb database, and use embedded structur. For exemple, consider that the size of each document of the **persons** 's collection is 16MB. It means that i can not add the sub-document **contacts** in the person's collection.
1- In this case what should i do ?
2- If i create the collection of contact, it will be an obligation to reference to the a person.
Can we have embeded and reference stuctur in a mongodb database ?

Thank you.

```
{
    nom:'Kox', 
    prenom:'Karl', 
    gender:'M', 
    addres: 
        {
          rue: '123 Fake Street', 
          appt:108, 
          city:'mycity',
          zip_code:'GGG23'
        }, 
    class: 
        {
          name:'CLASS ONE', 
          group:'C', 
          section:'SECTION ONE' 
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the strengths of MongoDB is the flexible schema.

You can certainly have contacts embedded for some of person documents, referenced for others, or a single person document that has some of its contacts embedded and some referenced.

One possible use of this is to have recently or frequently used contacts embedded for quick access (similar to a per-person cache) and all contacts available for lookup via reference.

The natural extension of this is that if a person's entire contact list fits within the person document, there is never a need to do a separate contact lookup for that person.

The tradeoff is:

A referenced approach allows contact lists to be arbitrarily large, but requires a separate contact lookup aside from the person lookup.

An embedded approach reduces the load on the database server by requiring only 1 lookup for both person and contacts, but limits the size of the person + contact list to 16MB.

A hybrid embedded/referenced approach requires a bit more complexity in the application code, but provides a reduction in query load on the database server while still allowing a contact list to be extremely large.

Comment: @Joe.Thank you. Instead of some contacts in embed and some in reference, i think it's more simple and to create another collection (contact) and reference it in the person's collection:(a person can have many contact). What do you think ?

Comment: That does simplify the application code at the expense of requiring a separate lookup each time.  Which of the 3 methods is better will depend on the data, the required response times, they query patterns, and the expected load.